# Pandas: Create missing combination rows with zero values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,2,2,2], 'col2': ['A','B','A','B','C'], 'value': [2,4,6,8,10]})

    col1 col2 value
0   1    A    2
1   1    B    4
2   2    A    6
3   2    B    8
4   2    C    10
```

I'm looking for a way to create any missing rows among the possible combination of `col1` and `col2` with exiting values, and fill in the missing rows with zeros

The desired result would be:

```
    col1 col2 value
0   1    A    2
1   1    B    4
2   2    A    6
3   2    B    8
4   2    C    10
5   1    C    0    <- Missing the "1-C" combination, so create it w/ value = 0
```

I've looked into using `stack` and `unstack` to make this work, but I'm not sure that's exactly what I need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way using `unstack` with `fill_value=0` and `stack`, `reset_index`

```
df.set_index(['col1','col2']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()

Out[311]:
   col1 col2  value
0     1    A      2
1     1    B      4
2     1    C      0
3     2    A      6
4     2    B      8
5     2    C     10
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `pivot` , then `stack`

```
df.pivot(*df.columns).fillna(0).stack().to_frame('values').reset_index()
Out[564]: 
   col1 col2  values
0     1    A     2.0
1     1    B     4.0
2     1    C     0.0
3     2    A     6.0
4     2    B     8.0
5     2    C    10.0
```

Comment: Wish I could check multiple answers, as this works perfectly as well. For some other reasons related to the actual data I'm working with, I marked the answer from @Andy above as the solution since it's easier for me to implement into what I'm working on. Thanks for this though, very cool solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) + [MultiIndex.from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product):

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.col1.unique(), df.col2.unique()])

result = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2']).reindex(index, fill_value=0).reset_index()

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   col1 col2  value
0     1    A      2
1     1    B      4
2     1    C      0
3     2    A      6
4     2    B      8
5     2    C     10
```